# How to select a column from multiple tables in c#?

Tags: c#, mysql

my problem comes from the fact that I'm very new to this. Basically, I'm kind of trying to make a restapi in c# and it's currently connected to a mysql databse on my localhost. I have multiple tables with relations and from one of the tables, I want to list all the records from that table where its relations contain a specific string in their tables.

Let's say I have a Building table which has multiple columns, batteries and elevators. I'd want to list all the buildings where it has either a column, battery or elevator with an 'inactive' status, status being the column name.

My code currently looks as follow, though obviously wrong :

```
[HttpGet("intervention")]
public List<Buildings> Getintervention(string status)
{
    var myintervention = _context.buildings.Select(e => e.status == "Inactive").From(Batteries).ToList();
    return myintervention;
}
```

I know for a fact I could do a query like this and it works : `var unavailable = _context.elevators.Where(e => e.status != "Active").ToList();`

Problem is... I don't know how to do it since my Building table does not have any status column and currently it returns me an error saying that.. it doesn't contain a status column. lol.

If anyone has an idea of how I could do this, let me know!

Thank you :)

Comment: Can you share structure of Building table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not clear on whether this is EF or EF core and/or how you load your related data but I would expect it to look like this if the building collection has already eagerly loaded or will implicitly load the batteries / columns / elevators:

```
context.Buildings.Where(b =>
  b.Batteries.Any(ba => ba.Status == "Inactive) ||
  b.Columns.Any(c => c.Status == "Inactive) ||
  b.Elevators.Any(c => c.Status == "Inactive)
);
```

If a Building doesn't load these collections / they are loaded explicitly you might need to do something like `context.Buildings.Include(b=>b.Batteries).Include(b=>b.Columns)...` before your where. You should be mindful that in recent versions of EF core that joins are used rather than running separate queries and multiple includes may cause a Cartesian explosion (a building with 10 batteries, 10 columns and 10 elevators will cause 1000 rows to be generated, and EF will have to pick through the result set to boil it back down to 31 entities)

It may this be more performant to hit your tables individually, collecting buildings or building ids from them:

```
context.Batteries(b=> b.Status == "Inactive").Select(ba => ba.Building);
context.Batteries(b=> b.Status == "Inactive").Select(ba => ba.BuildingID);
```

And then later (retrieving buildings via the ids) then reporting on the buildings

Comment: I'm using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore and Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Infrastructure. Not so sure about the joins things though. Trying your solution now.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data for more info about loading the data from tables related to Buildings

Comment: If I were to do something like `var myintervention = _context.buildings.Include(b => b.batteries).Where(b => b.batteries.Any(ba => ba.Status == "Inactive"));` I still get "Buildings does not contain a definition for batteries" :(

Comment: It sounds like your data model hasn't been set up to know about the relationship a building has with a battery? I'm now not sure if your question is about querying related data or setting up the context so it knows how tables are related. Your Building entity needs a collection of batteries but how this is done depends on whether there is an interim BuildingBattery table breaking down a M:M relationship between buildings and batteries or whether it's a simple "1 building has many batteries/battery has a building ID"

Comment: You're right. I'm sorry, I'm mostly used to rails recently and totally forgot. I'll look it up since I just do something like this `public long adress_id { get; set; }` for the relations... This is very probably wrong since it'll just be a number lol

Comment: Take a look at eg https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-many-relationship-configuration - see how a Building has Batteries/ a Battery has Building? Naturally, given that's for EF core if you're using EF6 find an appropriately targeted tutorial

Comment: Somehow I could only add `public Batteries batteries { get; set; }` to my buildings model and public `Buildings buildings { get; set; }` to my batteries model. It wouldn't let me do like the tutorials with something like Icollection or List so now it's a one-on-one relationship and I get `The child/dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one relationship between 'Batteries.buildings' and 'Buildings.batteries'. To identify the child/dependent side of the relationship, configure the foreign key property.` Sucks haha

Comment: One battery has many buildings?thats the opposite of what your question said..

Comment: I got confused, I meant the opposite it was late. A building has many batteries!

Comment: And what EF are you using? 6 or Core? And what is the code that sets up your C# entities (it maybe mentions things like DBSet, HasMany, Map etc)

Comment: I managed to make it work for the relations. In all honesty, I don't even know what EF I'm using. For now, I managed to make it work by having `public Battery batteries { get; set; }` in my building model and     `[ForeignKey("building_id")]
    public Buildings buildings { get; set; }` in my battery model!

Comment: Since I fixed my relationships now, I still have the problem for the query. I made another post with more details. If you understand what I mean in my post, feel free to let me know what you think! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61003655/how-to-use-linq-in-c-sharp-to-select-a-specific-string-from-multiple-nested-colu