# How to use Linq in C# to select a specific string from multiple nested columns?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq

I have a small problem here. I have the following tables with their relations :

```
Building
  Batteries
    Columns
      Elevators
```

A building can have many batteries, batteries can have many columns, columns can have many elevators.

A battery has one building, a column has one battery, an elevator has one column.

If I were to do this `var myintervention = _context.buildings.Where(b => b.batteries.Any(ba => ba.status == "Intervention")).ToList();` it would work perfectly fine in my query to return a list of the buildings that have batteries with the intervention status (status is a column).

The problem is that I can't do something like `_context.buildings.Where(c => c.columns.Any...)` because the building model doesn't have access to the column class but the battery does... Same goes for elevators, buildings don't have access to elevators, columns do.

Here's how I defined my modelBuilder :

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Battery>()
            .HasOne(p => p.buildings)
            .WithMany(b => b.batteries)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.building_id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Column>()
            .HasOne(p => p.batteries)
            .WithMany(b => b.columns)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.battery_id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Elevator>()
            .HasOne(p => p.columns)
            .WithMany(b => b.elevators)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.column_id);
    }
```

Here's how my relations look in my models :

```
building.cs
  public List<Battery> batteries { get; set; }

battery.cs
  public long building_id { get; set; }
  public Building buildings { get; set; }
  public List<Column> columns { get; set; }

column.cs
  public long battery_id { get; set; }
  public Battery batteries { get; set; }
  public List<Elevator> elevators { get; set; }

elevator.cs
  public long column_id { get; set; }
  public Column columns { get; set; }
```

tl;dr; I want to do a linq query to list all the buildings that have either a battery, column or elevator whose's status column is at "Intervention".

UPDATE: apparently this somehow works, but not efficiently :

```
var myintervention = _context.buildings.Where(a => a.batteries.SelectMany(b => b.columns.SelectMany(c => c.elevators)).Any(c => c.status == "Intervention")).ToList();
```

It seems as though it's not accurate? Sometimes there are batteries in intervention and the building associated with those batteries doesn't appear in the building list. Same goes for elevators or columns.. I'm a bit lost!

UPDATE 2 : here's my request :

```
[HttpGet("intervention")]
        public List<Building> Getintervention(string status)
        {
            var myintervention = _context.buildings.Where(c => c.batteries.SelectMany(z => z.columns).Any(z => z.status == "Intervention")).ToList();
            return myintervention;
        }
```

Comment: `c.batteries.SelectMany(z => z.columns).Any` does that work?

Comment: Hmm something like `var myintervention = _context.buildings.Where(c => c.batteries.SelectMany(z => z.columns).Any(z => z.status == "Intervention")).ToList();` does work to show a list of buildings, but I'm sure as to what it's linked? When I check the ids of the selected buildings, it doesn't correspond to a column or battery with the intervention status :(

Comment: Any chance you can make the plurality of the property names agree with the singular/collection? eg battery.cs (should be called Battery.cs) should have `public Building Building` - it's confusing as *!%# to have a property with a plural name (so you assume it's a collection) but it be a single object (so you would expect to be able to say `buildings.Where` but you can only do that on collections. Property names in c# start with a Capital Letter

Comment: @JeunePadawan Rather then editing away your question, please delete it if you feel it is not useful anymore.

Answer (score 1):

First up, please fix the model so collections have plural names and objects have single, otherwise your code will become very confused:

```
building.cs
  public List<Battery> Batteries { get; set; }

battery.cs
  public long BuildingId { get; set; }
  public Building Building { get; set; }
  public List<Column> Columns { get; set; }

column.cs
  public long BatteryId { get; set; }
  public Battery Battery { get; set; }
  public List<Elevator> Elevators { get; set; }

elevator.cs
  public long ColumnId { get; set; }
  public Column Columns { get; set; }
```

Now let's add some more properties to the model so it can tell us about interventions:

```
building.cs
  public List<Battery> Batteries { get; set; }

  [NotMapped]
  public bool IsInIntervention => this.Status == "Intervention" || Batteries.Any(b => b.IsInIntervention);

battery.cs
  public long BuildingId { get; set; }
  public Building Building { get; set; }
  public List<Column> Columns { get; set; }

  [NotMapped]
  public bool IsInIntervention => this.Status == "Intervention" || Columns.Any(c => c.IsInIntervention);


column.cs
  public long BatteryId { get; set; }
  public Battery Battery { get; set; }
  public List<Elevator> Elevators { get; set; }

  [NotMapped]
  public bool IsInIntervention => this.Status == "Intervention" || Elevators.Any(e => e.IsInIntervention);


elevator.cs
  public long ColumnId { get; set; }
  public Column Column { get; set; }

  [NotMapped]
  public bool IsInIntervention => this.Status == "Intervention";
```

Now you can just ask a building if it IsInIntervention and it will say yes if it is or if anything it owns is

Note: if the model hasn't been loaded with entities then you might need to employ a trick like this: [EF Core linq and conditional include and theninclude problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53474431/ef-core-linq-and-conditional-include-and-theninclude-problem) to conditionally load them

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for all this... Yeah I was just changing everything right now, but I'm making mistakes left and right, I'm too tired considering it's past 2 am. I'm curious though, how would you do the query for IsInIntervention though? I updated the main post with the request I'm making. I'm sorry if this doesn't make sense, I'll read back everything tomorrow morning. Thanks a lot for all your help, I sincerely appreciate it.

Comment: Hm. Doesn't look like I can do the bool in the models, I get this error : An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Linq.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Value cannot be null.'. Tried fixing it but I'm not good enough lol

Comment: I think it'll be because the data isn't loaded so eg build.Batteries is null; did you see that link I pasted about querying with include/theninclude ? How many buildings/batteries/columns/elevators are we talking about ?

Comment: It works now! Edited the question to show the answer!

Comment: Probably shouldn't edit a question so drastically as to make the answers meaningless - post your edit as an answer (and you can accept it ) and mark any other answers that were helpful, with an upvote. To access the edit revision of the question (copy your current edit the revert the question to the earlier edit and post the copied text as an answer) hit the "edited x mins ago" link on the question

Comment: True next time I'll do that! Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

```
var vara = _context.maintable.Where(a => a.tablerelatedtomain.SelectMany(b => b.tablerelatedtoprevious).SelectMany(c => c.tablerelatedtoprevious).Any(c => c.status == "mystring")).ToList();
var varb = _context.maintable.Where(a => a.tablerelatedtomain.SelectMany(b => b.tablerelatedtoprevious).Any(b => b.status == "mystring")).ToList();
var varc = _context.maintable.Where(a => a.tablerelatedtomain.Any(a => a.status == "mystring")).ToList();
var result = vara.Union(varb).Union(varc).OrderBy(z => z.id).ToList();

return result;
```